# Puzzled about (lack of?) Apple SIM

Tags: ipad, sim

Apple's store web pages began saying some time ago that cell-enabled iPads include an Apple SIM.

I have a barely working iPad that I had a data plan on in Korea in February.  But because it is broken, I bought another about a month ago.

The new one is interrupts me with annoying frequency to tell me it has no SIM card.  To make it shut up, I decided to transfer the SIM from the broken one.  Popped out both trays, and NEITHER contains a SIM card.

Is the SIM that the store claims is included built-in somewhere?  If so, why does one of them say it doesn't exist? and does the tray indicate it is a dual-SIM device?

Comment: Your original iPad is equipped with an "embedded Apple SIM", see https://techcrunch.com/2016/03/23/explainer-alert-heres-what-the-ipad-pros-embedded-apple-sim-means-for-you/, https://everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/ipad-air-faq/what-is-apple-sim-different-from-nano-sim.html, https://www.ibtimes.co.uk/apple-sim-how-does-it-work-end-sim-cards-1471065, https://appleinsider.com/articles/16/03/22/apple-makes-the-move-to-embedded-sim-card-with-97-ipad-pro, http://pocketnow.com/2016/03/23/embedded-apple-sim

Comment: That page has the explanation: the removable SIM was omitted because I bought it in Spain.